# Spring Integration manually publish message to channel

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm in the process of learning how to use the Java Spring Framework and started experimenting with Spring Integration. I'm trying to use Spring Integration to connect my application to an MQTT broker both to publish and subscribe to messages but I'm having trouble finding a way to manually publish messages to an outbound channel. If possible I want to build it using notations in the java code exclusively rather than xml files defining beans and other related configuration.

In every example I've seen the solution to manually publishing a message seems to be to use a MessagingGateway Interface and then use the SpringApplicationBuilder to get the ConfigurableApplicationContext to get a reference to the gateway interface in the main method. The reference is then used to publish a message. Would it be possible to use AutoWired for the interface instead? In my attempts I just get a NullPointer.

My aim is to build a game where I subscribe to a topic to get game messages and then whenever the user is ready to make the next move, publish a new message to the topic.

**Update**:
This is one of the examples I've been looking at of how to setup an outbound channel: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mqtt.html

**Update 2 after answer from Gary Russel:**

This is some example code I wrote after looking at examples which gets me a NullPointer when using @AutoWired for the Gateway when running gateway.sendToMqtt in Controller.java.  What I want to achieve here is to send an mqtt message manually when a GET request is handled by the controller.

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/publishMessage")
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    static Gateway gateway;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public int request(){
        gateway.sendToMqtt("Test Message!");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

MqttPublisher.java

```
@EnableIntegration
@Configuration
public class MqttPublisher {
    @Bean
    public MqttPahoClientFactory mqttClientFactory(){
        DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory factory = new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();
        factory.setServerURIs("tcp://localhost:1883");
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqttOutboundChannel")
    public MessageHandler mqttOutbound(){
        MqttPahoMessageHandler messageHandler =
                new MqttPahoMessageHandler("clientPublisher", mqttClientFactory());
        messageHandler.setAsync(true);
        messageHandler.setDefaultTopic("topic");
        return messageHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel mqttOutboundChannel(){
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "mqttOutboundChannel")
    public interface Gateway {

        void sendToMqtt(String data);
    }
}
```

**Update**:

Not sure if this is the proper logging but it is what I get from adding:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=Debug
logging.level.org.hibernate=Error
```

to application.properties.

https://hastebin.com/cuvonufeco.hs

Comment: If you have a problem with your code, you need to post your code as a [mcve] with a good description of the problem and where exactly in your code it occurs.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt: This is not really a problem with my code but rather a question of how and if this can be done.

Comment: How does it work if you remove `static` from the `Gateway` property?

Comment: @ArtemBilan: If I remove static my IDE complains that "No beans of 'Gateway' type found"

Comment: Well, that’s just IDE issue. You don’t have it at runtime, especially in production

Comment: @ArtemBilan Yeah, you were right. Seems to work without static. My IDE complains but it runs fine.

Comment: That’s the point! So, time to accept Gary’s answer and him thank you 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [Messaging Gateway](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#gateway) or simply send a message to the channel.

**EDIT**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So47846492Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So47846492Application.class, args).close();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(MyGate gate) {
        return args -> {
            gate.send("someTopic", "foo");
            Thread.sleep(5_000);
        };
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toMqtt")
    public MqttPahoMessageHandler mqtt() {
        MqttPahoMessageHandler handler = new MqttPahoMessageHandler("tcp://localhost:1883", "foo",
                clientFactory());
        handler.setDefaultTopic("myTopic");
        handler.setQosExpressionString("1");
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    public MqttPahoClientFactory clientFactory() {
        DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory factory = new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();
        factory.setUserName("guest");
        factory.setPassword("guest");
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter mqttIn() {
        MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter =
                new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter("tcp://localhost:1883", "bar", "someTopic");
        adapter.setOutputChannelName("fromMqtt");
        return adapter;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fromMqtt")
    public void in(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "toMqtt")
    public interface MyGate {

        void send(@Header(MqttHeaders.TOPIC) String topic, String out);

    }

}
```

Comment: I assume that MessagingGateway should be the annotation of an interface, but what implements this interface? Could you give me an example of how to use the Messaging Gateway or how to send a message to the channel without doing it in the main method, or atleast without first getting the context?

Comment: The framework implements the interface (via the `GatewayProxyFactoryBean`). You can `@Autowire` the gateway or provide it as a parameter to the bean factory method - see the edit to my answer.

Comment: Could you @AutoWired MyGate gate and use that reference to call send in the main method or any other class without using ApplicationRunner?

Comment: Yes, of course (but not in the main method); I said that in my comment above; I just did that for expediency. In the main method you would have to call `getBean()` on the application context.

Comment: I'm trying to use @ AutoWired in a @ RestController but this is where I get NullPointer, see my updated question for an example. Is the controller in some way outside the scope such that it can not access the interface?

Comment: Wierd. Is the controller in the same package as the boot app? If not you need to component scan that package too. DEBUG logging context initialization should help.

Comment: Yes, they are in the same package. I updated my answer with debug logging. I'm however not totally sure if it is the correct debug logging for context initialization.